# Can't import python module from separate partition

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently copied my "scripts" folder to a seperate partition (from C:\ to drive D:\ ) while the python interpreter (v2.7.13) is still on C:\ . Subsequently I updated my $PATH to include the new path.

Now I try to execute a python script that imports modules from my "scripts" and it cannot find those modules:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "neue_aufgabe.py", line 15, in <module>
      from CustomUtils.UI.PyQtUI import *
ImportError: No module named CustomUtils.UI.PyQtUI
```

So, we have:

---

Interpreter   on C:\

Modules on D:\

Script to be run on D:\

---

I deleted all the stale pyc files from all module directories. Is it just that the interpreter cannot import a module from a seperate partition?

Comment: Is the directory structure of the project now changed? Is there a folder called CustomUtils in the same directory as neue_aufgabe.py ?

Comment: The structure CustomUtils.UI.PyQtUI was still the same (importan of course). Problem was that python looks in the PYTHONPATH for modules and not in PATH

Answer (score 4):

You need to append your new folder to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable rather than `PATH`.

Alternatively you can set it in the script itself by putting this at the top (though not usually recommended in production)

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/modules')
```

Comment: Yup, that was quick, forgot about that... Thanks!